# Getting error for LISTAGG Function (result of string concatenation is too long)

Tags: sql, oracle, function, listagg

I am getting "ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long" while trying to execute below query.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(  (SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG(tb.CODE,',') WITHIN GROUP(
  ORDER BY tb.CODE )
  FROM TB041 tb,TB043 re
  WHERE tb.CODE = re.CODE
  and  re.id = 123
   AND re.pcode  = 234) ,'([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)'   ,'\1\3') from dual;
```

Result I am getting is when it is less than 4000 character : SA,FA,TS,KR,LS......................

I am getting error while LISTAGG trying to return more than 4000 character .
Please help me on this.

is there any way to trim this LISTAGG value or can I add any condition which will execute less than 4000 character.

Comment: What is your Oracle version? Also, why are you doing this in the first place? What will you do with the resulting, possibly very long, strings?

Comment: The link I closed your question with should give you various options to handle the problem that you are facing: use the `overflow` clause (available from version 12c) to truncate oversized lists, switch to `xmlagg()`, etc.